# Usage of $\cdot$ in calculus

Tags: calculus, notation, convention

I often find myself caught in the dilemma of whether or not to use the symbol $\cdot$ in calculus. Take for example, the chain rule:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$$

Is the $\cdot$ there really necessary? Can we write it simply instead as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$

How about the case when one considers axillary substitutions during integration, for example:

$$x = \sin\theta \implies dx = \cos\theta\cdot d\theta$$

Is the $\cdot$ here again necessary? Will $dx = \cos\theta d\theta$ be the same (I've seen a mixture of both quite often), by the strict standards of Mathematics? Up to date, all I've heard from my lecturers is that omitting the $\cdot$ is fine, although strictly speaking, it is necessary. But why so? What does the $\cdot$ mean?

Or is this all just a matter of preferences? If so, what best practices would you advise?

Thanks!

Comment: I have never seen the dot product operator used this way. Actually, let me ask you this. How do *you* interpret the dot operator here?

Comment: Generally I would remove symbols if doing so does not introduce ambiguity.

Comment: The dot operator is simply shorthand for '*' in most cases. In the case of both it should be acceptable to forgo use.

Comment: I use $\cdot$ for multiplication when it improves readability or provides meaning. For example, I find $n!\cdot 2^n$ to be more readable than $n!2^n$, even though it’s not needed, and for a product of integers, $2\cdot11\cdot13$ is unambiguous, while juxtaposition isn’t, and other options, like $(2)(11)(13)$ or $2\times11\times13$, are clunkier.

Comment: I agree with the others. Not using it is acceptable.

Comment: As a matter of typography, you need to separate a multi-letter symbol such as $dx$ from any letters that come before or after it.  Whatever you do, don't write $sinxdx$.  A space (even a small space such as \; in LaTeX) is usually acceptable, as is a dot.

Comment: You do want to be careful that your dot isn't mistaken for the dot-product symbol, or for the decimal point (which is raised in some styles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have seen in textbooks and the like, I have never seen the $\cdot$ symbol being used. The chain rule would be:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\color{green}{\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}}$$
A particular integral solvable by u-substitution would be written like:
$$\int \color{green}{\sin x \cos x \ dx}$$
$$u=\sin x$$
$$du = \color{green}{\cos x \ dx}$$

As for using the actual notation $\cdot$ is acceptable, I think it is allowed. Some other textbooks may have that notation, but I have not seen $\cdot$ to represent multiplication and the like. Now I do not want you to think you do not use $\cdot$ when dealing with *dot products*. I will stop here because I actually do not really know what a dot product is, other than the fact that it is related to vectors. You do *not* need to use the dot symbol (as pointed out by user Américo Tavares)
$$\color{green}{(-3, 4)\cdot \pmatrix{5\\-1} \ \text{is definitely correct.}}$$
$$\color{green}{(-3, 4)\pmatrix{5\\-1} \ \text{is also correct.}}$$

**Edit:** User Américo Tavares pointed out in a comment that $(-3, 4)\pmatrix{5\\-1}$ $\color{green}{\text{is correct}}$.

Comment: You don't know because it doesn't make sense two multiply two row vectors :) . OTOH, $(3\;2)\begin{pmatrix}4\\1\end{pmatrix}$ makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you for your input

Comment: ${(-3, 4)\pmatrix{5\\-1} }$ is correct because one assumes that two matrices are beeing multiplied: the $1\times 2$-matrix  ${(-3, 4)}$   and the $2\times 1$-matrix ${\pmatrix{5\\-1} }$.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with analysis vs linear algebra the concepts of $\cdot$ vs $\times$ vs * are all the same in real analysis and are just multiplication.  Multiplication of vectors is different.  Multiplying two vectors by $\cdot$ produces a number (called a scalar) and we refer to that operation as a dot product.  When you multiply two vectors using the $\times$ symbol this refers to a cross product and produces another vector.  These concepts are not in a beginning calculus or real analysis course so you should view the use of $\cdot$ as a purely aesthetic way of denoting multiplication.